# $\chi^2$ distribution as sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Hi how to show the following: $\chi^2$

$\frac{2(\sum_{i=1}^{r}Y_i + (n-r)Y_r)}{\theta}$ is a chi-square dristribution with 
$2r$ degrees of freedom where:

$Y_i$ stands for the order statistics of i.i.d r.v.'s $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...X_n$ with exponential densities 
$\frac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{x}{\theta}}$ and hence $Y_1 \leq Y_2 \leq ... \leq Y_r$ and 
$Y_i = X_(i)$.

I wrote the the joint density of $(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_r)$ but nothing became apparent. Thank you for your time.